# PHP - File Upload Security, Why Won't This Method Work?

Tags: php, file, security, upload

I'm new to file uploading, and I realize that security is HUGE. Now per testing purposes before I really wanted to dive into the security I wanted to just get a quick test upload going, when I tried the following "security"

```
<?PHP
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

if(isset($name)) {
    if (!empty($name)) {
    $location = "ufiles/";  
    if($_FILES['file']['type'] == "images/jpeg" || $_FILES['file']['type'] == "images/png"){

    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name);
                }
            }
        }
?>
```

This code does not appear to work, and the file will not upload unless I take off the file type check point. So it's obviously my issue. But why does this not work?

**also:** I realize it's not a very effective way of securing file types, but it seems most simply logical, and I'm just very confused why it doesn't work.

**Edit** ALWAYS CHECK YOUR SYNTAX. lol

```
if($_FILES['file']['type'] == "images/jpeg" || $_FILES['file']['type'] == "images/png")
```

Comment: $_FILES *not* $_files

Comment: This was it...Man oh man. I feel stupid right now...DOH! =[ Thank you though :P

Comment: @Dagon Wow... Beat me to it. Haha. Rbn, PHP Variables are case sensitive.

Comment: @Oberst Yeah, it was just me being me, and I messed up and simply typed in lower cases.

Answer (score 1):

It's "image/jpeg" not "image**s**/jpeg". Same goes for the PNG type.

**$_files** should also be **$_FILES** as mentioned by Oberst & Dagon. PHP variables are case-sensitive.

Like so:

```
if(isset($name)) {
    if (!empty($name)) {
    $location = "ufiles/";  
    if($_FILES['file']['type'] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES['file']['type'] == "image/png"){

    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name);
                }
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: PHP variables are STILL case sensitive. ;-) (as per my comment above)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is  the problem with the

```
$_files['file']['type'] == "images/jpeg" || $_files['file']['type'] == "images/png";
```

please replace `$_FILES['file']['type']` instead of that and try it or you can put `$type` as you define above.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the content types to `image/jpeg` and `image/png`

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily bypassed as the media type in `$_FILES['file']['type']` can be forged.

If you only want to allow images, make sure you’re saving them using an appropriate file name extensions. Otherwise, an attacker can upload `.php` files as `image/png` which would bypass your validation.